# Developing chrome app for displaying webpage

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am trying to develop a chrome app and I am new to this. How do I create a chrome app to display webpage and update when ever the information on webpage is updated (without reloading the chrome app explicitly)  or how do I reload the page every few seconds in the background?

Thanks,

Comment: can you please show us what you have tried

Comment: also knowing the context in which you want to deploy the app would help, suggesting what restrictions if any might apply.

Comment: @james, DanSut: I have added below code in manifest json file  {
  "name": "App test",
  "description": "chrome app test",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://oceanic-antler-103523.appspot.com/view_photo"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://oceanic-antler-103523.appspot.com/view_photo"
    }
  }
}

Comment: And I have another code (python program) to upload new images/video which are updated at above web url

Answer (score 0):

You could use the webview tag:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview to display a website in your chrome app.

To refresh the content in de webview you can use the alarm API https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms.